# How can you write musical notation in Mathematica?

Tags: packages, sound

I am trying to write a project that overlaps particle physics and music, and have written all the basis in Mathematica, but to display it I need to write some lines of music out. I deally I would like to write it in the same form as https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LearnMusicalNotes/. I can't find what that would be, does anyone know what package this is? I can't fin the souce code.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a package that the author is using. Below the demonstration, you should seek 3 buttons: Download to Desktop, Copy to Clipboard, and Source. If you click the Source button, it should download a notebook containing all of the code needed to create the demonstration. The code itself is typically hidden for clarity, but to the far right of the demonstration itself you should see the thin grey bar the denotes the cells. One of the grey bars should have a triangle shape at the top of it. Double-click that bar in order to show the code.

Comment: The answer would appear to be "With great effort"